# How to make objects transparent in OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm using OpenTK and C#, I have defined a plane in 3D space as follows:

```
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
GL.Color3(Color.Magenta);
GL.Vertex3(-100.0f, -25.0f, -150.0f);
GL.Vertex3(-100.0f, -25.0f,  150.0f);
GL.Vertex3( 200.0f, -25.0f,  100.0f);
GL.Vertex3( 200.0f, -25.0f, -100.0f);
GL.End();
```

Can anyone please help me to make the plane transparent?

Comment: You mean translucent instead of transparent, right?

Comment: No, I mean transparent. Anyhow, will there be any difference in code for translucent?

Comment: Something transparent you cannot see, so it is pretty easy to code. Translucent on the other hand is much harder.

Comment: Is it wise to use OpenTK now that t has been abandoned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you want something like this?

[image: Picture]

There are a lot of things to take care of to get there.

It all starts with a `Color` object that contains an alpha value<255. For example `Color.FromArgb(85, Color.Turquoise)` for the sphere below.

The main render class, sets up the camera view and renders all the lights, and then renders all the objects in the scene:

```
    public void RenderOnView(GLControl control)
    {
        control.MakeCurrent();
        var camera=views[control];
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit|ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.CullFace);
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        camera.LookThrough();
        if (EnableLights)
        {
            GL.LightModel(LightModelParameter.LightModelAmbient, new[] { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f });
            GL.LightModel(LightModelParameter.LightModelLocalViewer, 1);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
            foreach (var light in lights)
            {
                light.Render();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
            GL.ShadeModel(ShadingModel.Flat);
        }
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.LineSmooth); // This is Optional 
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Normalize);  // These is critical to have
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.RescaleNormal);
        for (int i=0; i<objects.Count; i++)
        {
            GL.PushMatrix();
            objects[i].Render();
            GL.PopMatrix();
        }
        control.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Then each object has a base rendering code `Render()`, which calls more specialized code `Draw()`

```
    public void Render()
    {
        if (Shading==ShadingModel.Smooth)
        {
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);
            GL.ColorMaterial(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, ColorMaterialParameter.AmbientAndDiffuse);
            GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Specular, SpecularColor);
            GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Emission, EmissionColor);
            GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Shininess, Shinyness);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        }
        else
        {
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        }
        GL.ShadeModel(Shading);
        GL.Translate(Position);
        GL.Scale(Scale, Scale, Scale);

        Draw(); // Draws triangles and quads to make up a shape
    }
```

and for example to draw a quad surface you have

```
    protected void DrawQuad(Color color, params Vector3[] nodes)
    {
        GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Fill);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.PolygonOffsetFill);
        // special code when translucent
        if (color.A<255)
        {
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
            GL.DepthMask(false);
        }
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
        GL.Color4(color);    //this is where the color with alpha is used
        for (int i=0; i<nodes.Length; i++)
        {
            GL.Vertex3(nodes[i]);
        }
        GL.End();
        // special code when translucent
        if (color.A<255)
        {
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
            GL.DepthMask(true);
        }
    }
```

also the code to draw the outline of a quad to be called after `DrawQaud()`

```
    protected void DrawLineLoop(Color color, params Vector3[] nodes)
    {
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.PolygonOffsetFill);
        GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Line);
        if (color.A<255)
        {
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
            GL.DepthMask(false);
        }
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.LineLoop);
        GL.Color4(color);
        for (int i=0; i<nodes.Length; i++)
        {
            GL.Vertex3(nodes[i]);
        }
        GL.End();
        if (color.A<255)
        {
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
            GL.DepthMask(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Always draw your translucent objects last. In your draw routine you need to draw all opaque objects _FIRST_, then draw all your translucent objects.

Comment: isn't it a bit heavy for a first try?

Comment: It is here for when it is needed.

Comment: Thank you.That's what I want, but it seems bit tough to understand. I found a simple solution, which I have posted below.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found solution of my question:

```
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.One);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);

//Definition of Plane
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
GL.Color4(0, 0.2, 1, 0.5);
GL.Vertex3(-100.0f, -25.0f, -150.0f);
GL.Vertex3(-100.0f, -25.0f,  150.0f);
GL.Vertex3( 200.0f, -25.0f,  100.0f);
GL.Vertex3( 200.0f, -25.0f, -100.0f);
GL.End();

GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
```

Comment: you may have checked my answer as approved :-)

Comment: The most important thing is to use BlenFunc and enable the cap BEFORE GL.Begin as harishli2020 posted above.

Answer (score 2):

In computing, Transparency effects are fained using [color blending](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending).For The special case of transprency, we talk about Àlpha Blending`

For transparency the blending factor is usualy stored in the 4th component of the colour (the `A` in RGBA) which stands for `alpha`. So you have to set all your colors with it.

example for half transparent blue (like glass):

```
GL.Color4(0,0,1,0.5f);
```

In OpenGL, blending have to be activated with the following command, which enable a supplementary stage on the rendering pipeline.

```
GL.Enable( EnableCap.Blend );
```

Then, because blending could be used to mix colors for other purpose than transparency, you have to specify the [blending function](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) to use. Here is the common function for transparency:

```
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
```

http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/opengl/fragment-ops/blending

Comment: Don't forget to disable depth check `GL.DepthMask(false);` before drawing with `GL.BlendFunc()` as specified. And _always_ draw your translucent objects last.

Comment: @ja72: default depth testing is ok (I guess), I've tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: If you are drawing one thing then depth test does not matter. In general though, it needs to be off on the 2nd pass for drawing correctly translucency.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use GL.Color4 instead of GL.Color3. The 4th value will be the alpha

Comment: I have used GL.Color4(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5); and then later GL.Color4(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0); but still my plane doesn't become transparent.