# Set color for a 3d Cone in OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, glut

I'm learning about OpenGL and I use C# for it.
I want to have a red cone and an opportunity to change its transparency.

This is what I do:

```
Gl.glColor4f(255, 0, 0, alpha);
Glut.glutSolidCone(cone.Radius, cone.Height, cone.Slices, cone.Stacks);
```

As a result I get something like this:

[image: Cone]

So it really is a cone but the color is just white (alpha = 1 when ran).

How to achieve the red color with an ability to make it transparent?

Comment: Not familiar with the `C#` API but I'd expect `glColor4f` to take parameters in the range [0, 1].

Comment: also if you have lighting enabled then in order to make `glColor` not be ignored you have  to `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);` otherwise you have to change light and or material properties to affect color... Transparency is depending on your `glBlendFunc` settings and it must be also enabled ...  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your replies!
Finally, got a solution:

```
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_BLEND);
Gl.glBlendFunc(Gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, Gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
Gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0, 0, alpha);
Glut.glutSolidCone(cone.Radius, cone.Height, cone.Slices, cone.Stacks);
```

So I have a Scroll Bar to change alpha parameter and the cone does change its transparency.

Comment: most likely your 255.0 got clamped to 1.0 the range is `<0.0,1.0>` for `glColor?f` once you want less saturated color you have to go below 1.0 ... like 0.75 ,...

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097005/380384) helps also.

> [image: fig1]
>
> The main render class, sets up the camera view and renders all the lights, and then renders all the objects in the scene:
>
> ```
>    public void RenderOnView(GLControl control)
>    {
>        control.MakeCurrent();
>        var camera = views[control];
>        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit|ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
>        GL.Disable(EnableCap.CullFace);
>        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
>        camera.LookThrough();
>        if (EnableLights)
>        {
>            GL.LightModel(LightModelParameter.LightModelAmbient, new[] { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f });
>            GL.LightModel(LightModelParameter.LightModelLocalViewer, 1);
>            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
>            foreach (var light in lights)
>            {
>                light.Render();
>            }
>        }
>        else
>        {
>            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
>            GL.ShadeModel(ShadingModel.Flat);
>        }
>        GL.Enable(EnableCap.LineSmooth); // This is Optional 
>        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Normalize);  // These is critical to have
>        GL.Enable(EnableCap.RescaleNormal);
>        for (int i = 0; i<objects.Count; i++)
>        {
>            GL.PushMatrix();
>            objects[i].Render();
>            GL.PopMatrix();
>        }
>        control.SwapBuffers();
>    }
> ```